# Python 3.4.3 - printing multiple ints per line

Tags: python

I ask for an input(X) and print 1 - 1000. X is used to print X amount of ints per line. How do I achieve this?

```
perLine = int(input("How many numbers per line would you like: "))

for lineVariable in range(1, 1000, 1):
   print(lineVariable)
```

example output(5)

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: increment a var in the loop, when var==x, insert a line break.

Comment: [FizzBuzz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz#Programming_interviews)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does what you were asking:

```
per_line = int(input("How many numbers per line would you like: "))

for number in range(1, 1001):
    print(number, end = " " if number % per_line else "\n")
```

Giving you the following output:

```
How many numbers per line would you like: 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
.
.
981 982 983 984 985 986 987 988 989 990
991 992 993 994 995 996 997 998 999 1000
```

Or for a version that uses Python's [grouper recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
per_line = int(input("How many numbers per line would you like: "))

for line in zip(*[iter(range(1, 1001))] * per_line):
    print(" ".join([str(x) for x in line]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perLine = int(input("How many numbers per line would you like: "))


rn = map(str, range(1, 1000, 1))
from itertools import islice

print("\n".join([" ".join(islice(rn, perLine))
      for _ in range(1, 1000, perLine)]).rstrip())
```

Comment: This gives the output desired, however it seems to be way more complicated.

Comment: It groups the elements in groups of upto five elements, if you just want a simple solution to just print use `if not i % perLine:print("")` to separate the output and `end = " "` to print each i,  it is never too early to learn about itertools

Answer (score 0):

Insert a line break only when "lineVariable" is a multiple of X :

```
perLine = int(input("How many numbers per line would you like: "))

for lineVariable in range(1, 1001):
   print(lineVariable, end=" ")
   if lineVariable%perLine==0:
        print("")
```

Note that, even if starting with 1 and not 0, if you want to have 1000 values printed, you have to use range(1, 1001).

Answer (score -1):

```
perLine = int(input("How many numbers per line would you like: "))

for lineVariable in range(1, 1000, 1):
   print(lineVariable * perLine)
```

Comment: I believe the desired behavior is to have consecutive integers on the same line, not X times the same.